# Evaluate an expression using named variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am looking for a way to evaluate an expression using temporary variables, a bit like the syntax of `glue::glue()`, preferentially from base R or from some tidyverse package.

For instance, in a dplyr pipeline, if my variable names have to be long, a simple calculation can look really awkward:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
set.seed(1)
options(pillar.sigfig=2)
df=tibble(a_very_long_variable_name1=rnorm(3), 
          a_very_long_variable_name2=rnorm(3))
df %>% 
  mutate(reldiff=(a_very_long_variable_name1/a_very_long_variable_name2 - lag(a_very_long_variable_name1/a_very_long_variable_name2))/lag(a_very_long_variable_name1/a_very_long_variable_name2))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   a_very_long_variable_name1 a_very_long_variable_name2 reldiff
#>                        <dbl>                      <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1                      -0.63                       1.6    NA   
#> 2                       0.18                       0.33   -2.4 
#> 3                      -0.84                      -0.82    0.83
```

This code indeed has really poor readability.

To improve on this, I could define a custom function or use `glue()`:

```r
f = function(x) (x-lag(x))/lag(x)
df %>% 
  mutate(reldiff=f(a_very_long_variable_name1/a_very_long_variable_name2), 
         reldiff2=glue("{(x-lag(x))/lag(x)}", 
                       x=a_very_long_variable_name1/a_very_long_variable_name2) %>% as.numeric())
#> Warning in glue("{(x-lag(x))/lag(x)}", x = a_very_long_variable_name1/
#> a_very_long_variable_name2) %>% : NAs introduced by coercion
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   a_very_long_variable_name1 a_very_long_variable_name2 reldiff reldiff2
#>                        <dbl>                      <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1                      -0.63                       1.6    NA       NA   
#> 2                       0.18                       0.33   -2.4     -2.4 
#> 3                      -0.84                      -0.82    0.83     0.83
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

However, having a function for a single-use is not satisfying, and having to cast the result to numeric could be error-prone.

Is there a one-liner function that could run this?

```
reldiff=evalx((x-lag(x))/lag(x), x=a_very_long_variable_name1/a_very_long_variable_name2)`?
```

Comment: why not use indexing to select the variables instead of typing the whole name i.e. `df %>% 
  mutate(reldiff=f(.[[1]]/.[[2]]))`

Comment: Could maybe do: `x1<-sym("a_very_long_variable_name1"); x2<-sym("a_very_long_variable_name2"); mutate(df, reldiff=f(!!x1/!!x2) # Insert your lag operators here using !!xi, i in 1,2`. Or even better, do not use `really_long_variable_names` and use comments to define acronyms.

Comment: @akrun I thought of that, but readability is really important here so using indexing would feel wrong. Moreover, I'm no fan of indexing as column position can vary when datasets are wangled a lot, like mine is.

Comment: @Baraliuh I'm looking for a one-liner, like `glue()` is. I unfortunately cannot change the variable names without decreasing the readability, and I'm afraid using acronyms would make it even worst.